# Having Trouble Creating a Makefile in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal

Here is the error I receive when creating a makefile from the Terminal in Ubuntu:

```
~/Desktop/a4 $ make
cc     Makefile.c   -o Makefile
Makefile.c:1:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

```
OBJ = Source.o
OPTIONS = -g

a4: Source.c
        gcc $(OPTIONS) -o a4 $(OBJ)

Source.o: myHeader.h Source.c
    gcc $(OPTIONS) -c Source.c

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) a4

package:
    tar -cvf myAssmt.tar *.c *.h Makefile
```

Source is a .c file in a folder called a4, and my makefile is Makefile.c in the same folder.

Comment: Don't call your makefile `Makefile.c`. Call it `Makefile`. And careful with the spaces in it.

Comment: I concur with @Mat, I experienced similar errors when using spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: That's the problem, he doesn't use tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'm aware that the console is picky about tabs, and I do indent with them and not spaces. I will check the file name and see if that works, but I'm pretty sure I tried that as well and it gave me a different error. I will post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile without the .c solved my problem. Thanks guys!